# How to embed aar native android library into a React Native plugin

Tags: android, react-native, android-library, react-native-linking

I am created a private SDK for Android. So I have .aar library. 
I also made React Native bridge and everything works great. 
But The problem is how to include .aar file in my reactive plugin? 
So Gradle can pull it like other public libraries.